# How to parse a JSON string?

Tags: android, json

I have string like shown below:

```
{"data":"{\"methodName\":\"matchRequest\",\"arguments\":[{\"matchId\":2963,\"gamerName\":\"pro100_Ocean\",\"gamerId\":\"4c04d9f0-c1e7-410f-8ad8-a95922556bbd\",\"gamerFullName\":null,\"gamerPhotoUrl\":\"data\\\\user\\\\4c04d9f0-c1e7-410f-8ad8-a95922556bbd\\\\profile\\\\cropped3649162562321249118.jpg\",\"gamerRaiting\":1,\"gamerCardScore\":0,\"correctAnswerScore\":50,\"incorrectAnswerScore\":-50,\"isBot\":false,\"myCardScore\":0}],\"identifier\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"}"}
```

I take the text from the backend, and I need to take the data. How do I do it?

**UPDATE**

I want to use Gson, and I created Pojo class like below, but I needed to take the values as a string in the date key like json.(Perhaps you didn't understand me)

```
 data class RequestGameModel (
    @SerializedName("messageType")
    @Expose
    var messageType: Int? = null,

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    var data: String? = null)
```

Comment: this is a Kotlin question and not a Java question. I vote to reopen. I added the Java tag on the other question since it was Java related back then and the language tag was missing in my view.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the expected structure of the data, I recommended using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). You can find a pretty good tutorial [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-getting-started-with-java-json-serialization-deserialization), explaining how to deserialize a JSON string in the section *Basics of JSON-Java Deserialization*.

```
String userJson = "{'age':26,'email':'norman@futurestud.io','isDeveloper':true,'name':'Norman'}";  

Gson gson = new Gson();  
UserSimple userObject = gson.fromJson(userJson, UserSimple.class);
```

For your case, first make sure that your JSON string is properly formatted. I think it should look like that:

```
{
    "data": {
        "methodName": "matchRequest",
        "arguments": [
            {
                "matchId": 2963,
                "gamerName": "pro100_Ocean",
                "gamerId": "4c04d9f0-c1e7-410f-8ad8-a95922556bbd",
                "gamerFullName": null,
                "gamerPhotoUrl": "data\\\\user\\\\4c04d9f0-c1e7-410f-8ad8-a95922556bbd\\\\profile\\\\cropped3649162562321249118.jpg",
                "gamerRaiting": 1,
                "gamerCardScore": 0,
                "correctAnswerScore": 50,
                "incorrectAnswerScore": -50,
                "isBot": false,
                "myCardScore": 0
            }
        ],
        "identifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    }
}
```

So the `data` key in the root should be one of your models instead of a `String`. A possible model mapping is like following (I got rid of the `@SerializedName` and `@Expose` annotations to emphasize the structure):

```
data class RequestGameModel(
    val `data`: GameModel? = null
)

data class GameModel(
    val methodName: String? = null,
    val arguments: List<GameArguments>? = null,
    val identifier: String? = null
)

data class GameArguments(
    val matchId: Int = -1,
    val gamerName: String? = null,
    val gamerId: String? = null,
    val gamerFullName: String? = null,
    val gamerPhotoUrl: String? = null,
    val gamerRaiting: Int = 0,
    val gamerCardScore: Int = 0,
    val correctAnswerScore: Int = 0,
    val incorrectAnswerScore: Int = 0,
    val isBot: Boolean = false,
    val myCardScore: Int = 0
)
```

Note that I used `val` and not `var`, so make sure that you configured GSON to allow serialization of final fields.

Comment: Yes, I try use Gson, but I need to create class model like UserSimple in your example. ( I updated my question)

Comment: I edited my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) for that:

```
val jsonObj = JSONObject("""{"hello": "world"}""")

jsonObj.getString("hello") // world
```

Note: You will request the JSON most likely from a REST API, but if you may need to hardcode a JSON string or just want to play around with it, Kotlin's raw strings will become handy (starting and ending with a tripple quote), since you don't have to escape single quotes then (as you did using backslashes).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the JSON string, you can either use external libraries like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) and [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to parse it for you or you can simply use `JSONObject` and do it yourself.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString)
```

Now you can easily fetch your data using various methods.

For example, to fetch a string value:

```
String value = object.getString("key")
```

to fetch a boolean value:

```
boolean value = object.getBoolean("key")
```

and so on. To know more check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject)

**PS:** *Kindly search your queries before posting them. There are high chances that you'll find them answered already.*
You can find it already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591098/9389481).

Comment: hey! unfortunately this is a Kotlin rather than a Java question :(